# how to implement friendships/exists in oriceon/oauth-5-laravel twitter api?

Tags: oauth, laravel-5, twitter-oauth

iam using  [oriceon/oauth-5-laravel](https://github.com/oriceon/oauth-5-laravel) .help me to implement **friendships/exists** .I want to post a request to follow particular person.help me.tysm advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the situation that you want to follow **NASA** in twitter.*NASA* is the screen name of **NASA**.You should add screen name to the url as below.Add this method to your controller and do proper routing.

```
public function followWithTwitter(Request $request)
{

    $token  = $request->get('oauth_token');
    $verify = $request->get('oauth_verifier');

    $tw = \OAuth::consumer('Twitter');
    if ( ! is_null($token) && ! is_null($verify))
    {
        // This was a callback request from twitter, get the token
        $token = $tw->requestAccessToken($token, $verify);
        // Send a request with it
        $result = json_decode($tw->request('https://api.twitter.com/1.1/friendships/create.json?screen_name=NASA&follow=true','POST'), true);
        if (!$result){
            //do some tasks for calculating and database updation for following
            return ("failed");
        }
        else{
            //do some tasks for calculating and database updation for following
            return ("success");
        }
    }
    // if not ask for permission first
    else
    {

        // get request token
        $reqToken = $tw->requestRequestToken();
        // get Authorization Uri sending the request token
        $url = $tw->getAuthorizationUri(['oauth_token' => $reqToken->getRequestToken()]);

        // return to twitter login url
        return redirect((string)$url);
    }
}
```